# Magento : how to add featured products in homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, featured-product

I installed a new theme, I dont know how to add featured products
 in homepage for my magento1.9.0.1.. please help me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets check the below links to add feature products on home page:

https://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/blog/61-must-know-tips/50209-how-to-add-featured-products-to-magento-frontend-step-by-step-instructions

Comment: but this work for my theme??